# Struts2 tags in javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, struts2

i'm working in a project with struts2 and i have a jsp page with bootstrap dynamic table. When i try adding row containing just text field it work perfectly.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var counter = 0;

        $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
            var newRow = $("<tr>");
            var cols = "";

            cols += '<td><s:textfield type="text" class="form-control" name="catalogue.lignes[' + counter + '].id.catalogue.ID_CATALOGUE"/></td>';
            cols += '<td><s:textfield type="text" class="form-control" name="catalogue.lignes[' + counter + '].id.avantage.ID_AVANTAGE"/></td>';
            cols += '<td><s:textfield type="text" class="form-control" name="catalogue.lignes[' + counter + '].DATE_DEBUT"/></td>';
            cols += '<td><s:textfield type="text" class="form-control" name="catalogue.lignes[' + counter + '].DATE_FIN"/></td>';
            cols += '<td><s:textfield type="text" class="form-control" name="catalogue.lignes[' + counter + '].POINTS_EQUIV"/></td>';
            cols += '<td><s:textfield type="text" class="form-control" name="catalogue.lignes[' + counter + '].QUANTITE"/></td>';

            cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger "  value="Supprimer"></td>';
            newRow.append(cols);
            $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
            counter++;
        });
```

But the problem appear when i try to add a row containing a struts2 list  or a a struts2 dojo compenent like calendar .

My java script code don't read this two tags. knowing i'm using a maven project.

Comment: JS - client. JSP - server. Look at your rendered JS and/or your JS console. You're mixing server-side and client-side code--it just doesn't work like this. And in this case you don't even need it,  you just need to render what the S2 code would render.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use `ajax` and get list as json. Then you can use that list to render new row in using javasript.

```
jQuery.ajax({
              url: 'youraction.action',
              success: function(list){
                //use this list to render new row
              },
              error: function(response){
                  console.log("error");
              }
});
```